# A text based DND game, (im 3 months into coding)

Tags: python, game

This is going to include my original code, and also revisions I have made, so far I have gotten some help on my character creations portion, and have revised it.

I  just would like input as to where I could simplify, and possibly fun features to play around with.

Original Code

Feel free to copy and paste it and run it, no errors as far as im aware

```
import random 
import replit
import time




#Character Creation and Intro
while True:
  print ("Thank you for playing my game")
  theClasses = ["Warrior", "Sentinal"]
  name = input("Enter a name for your character: ")
  print ("Hello " + name + " you are about to embark on an adventure")
  print ("..................")
  print ("You will now choose a starting class")
  print ("Your options are: ")
  print ("Warrior")
  print ("Sentinal")
  print ("..................")
  charDesc = input("if you would like a description of the class type please type their name if not type 'r':\n")
  theWarrior = "This class has increased damage, and base defense and luck"
  theSentinal = "This class has increased defense, and base damage and luck"
  # The warrior first choice
  if charDesc == "r":
    classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
    break
  if charDesc == "Warrior":
    print(theWarrior)
    nextChoice = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
  if nextChoice == "r":
    classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
    break
  if nextChoice == "e":
    charDesc2 = input("Please select another class: ")
    if charDesc2 == "Sentinal":
      print(theSentinal)
      nextChoice2 = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
      if nextChoice2 == "r":
        classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
        break
      if nextChoice2 == "e":
        charDesc3 = input("Please select another class: ")
        if charDesc3 == "Joker":
          print(theJoker)
          nextChoice3 = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
          if nextChoice3 == "r":
            classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
            break
          if nextChoice3 == "e":
            print("You have already learned about all the classes, please choose your class")
          classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
          break
  # The sentinal first choice
  if charDesc == "Sentinal":
    print(theSentinal)
    nextChoice = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
  if nextChoice == "r":
    classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
    break
  if nextChoice == "e":
    charDesc2 = input("Please select another class: ")
    if charDesc2 == "Warrior":
      print(theWarrior)
      nextChoice2 = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
      if nextChoice2 == "r":
        classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
        break
      if nextChoice2 == "e":
        charDesc3 = input("Please select another class: ")
        if charDesc3 == "Joker":
          print(theJoker)
          nextChoice3 = input("Press 'e' to choose a new class to learn about, or press 'r' to choose your class and press [enter]:\n")
          if nextChoice3 == "r":
            classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
            break
          if nextChoice3 == "e":
            print("You have already learned about all the classes, please choose your class")
            classChoice = input("Please choose your class: ")
            break
          
          
# Start of the game
if classChoice in theClasses:
  print("So a brave " + classChoice + " you are")
  myStartGameCommand = input("I won't hold you any longer, let your journey begin: press ['e' and hit enter] to begin:\n")
if myStartGameCommand == "e":
  replit.clear()
  time.sleep(1)

  
  
# First battle
print("'So you're the new " + classChoice + " around here'\n...")
print("'The last one died a very brutal death, so I'm sure you're optimistic'\n...")
print("'I wont hold you for too long, let's start your first battle, obviously an easy one'\n'Your first fight will be against a semi-smart training dummy, he can fight back'")
firstFightBegin = input("To begin battle press 'e':\n")
time.sleep(0.5)
replit.clear()



#First Enemy (Training Dummy)
enemyTrainingDummyHealth = 20
enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss = 5
enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit = 3
playerHealth = 50
if classChoice == "Sentinal":
  enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss = 4
  enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit = 2
while playerHealth >0:
  while enemyTrainingDummyHealth > 0:
    print("Level 1 Semi-Smart Training Dummy")
    print("HP:" + str(enemyTrainingDummyHealth) + "/20\n...") 
    print(name)
    print("HP:" + str(playerHealth) + "/50\n...")
    print ("The dummy looms over you, making you quiver, what's your first move\n...")
    print("'1. Attack'\n...")
    print("'2. Defend'")
    myChoiceDummy1 = input("What would you like to do? (type the number):\n")
    
    #Attack
    if myChoiceDummy1 == "1":
      replit.clear()
      print("Please choose an attack:\n1. Power Attack (50% chance to hit, deals increased damage)\n...\n2. Light Attack (Guarenteed hit, minimal damage)\n...\n3. Critical Attack (20% chance to hit, massive damage)\n...\n")
      attackChoice = input()
      
      
      # Light attack choice
      if attackChoice == "2":
        universalChance1 = random.randint(0,100)
        #if class is warrior and is sucessful
        if universalChance1 > 10:
          if classChoice == "Warrior":
            lightAttackChance1 = 3
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(lightAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - lightAttackChance1
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear() 
          #if class is not warrior
          if classChoice != "Warrior":
            lightAttackChance2 = 2
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(lightAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - lightAttackChance2
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
        #If light attack is unnsucessful
        if universalChance1 <= 10: 
          replit.clear()
          print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
          print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss) + " damage\n...")
          playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss
          time.sleep(2.5)
          replit.clear()
      
          
      #Power attack choice
      if attackChoice == "1":
        #if class is warrior
        universalChance2 = random.randint(0,100)
        #if class is warrior and is sucessful
        if universalChance2 > 50:
          if classChoice == "Warrior":
            powerAttackChance1 = random.randint(6,8)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(powerAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - powerAttackChance1
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear() 
          #if class is not warrior
          if classChoice != "Warrior":
            powerAttackChance2 = random.randint(5,7)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(powerAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - powerAttackChance2
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
        #If power attack is unnsucessful
        if universalChance2 <= 50: 
          replit.clear()
          print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
          print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss) + " damage\n...")
          playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss
          time.sleep(2.5)
          replit.clear()
      
          
      #Critical attack choice
      if attackChoice == "3":
          #if class is warrior
        universalChance3 = random.randint(0,100)
        #if class is warrior and is sucessful
        if universalChance3 > 80:
          if classChoice == "Warrior":
            criticalAttackChance1 = random.randint(10,15)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(criticalAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - criticalAttackChance1
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear() 
          #if class is not warrior
          if classChoice != "Warrior":
            criticalAttackChance2 = random.randint(5,7)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(criticalAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
            enemyTrainingDummyHealth = enemyTrainingDummyHealth - criticalAttackChance2
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
        #If critical attack is unnsucessful
        if universalChance3 <= 80: 
          replit.clear()
          print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
          print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss) + " damage\n...")
          playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyTrainingDummyDamageMiss
          time.sleep(2.5)
          replit.clear()
  if enemyTrainingDummyHealth <= 0:
    break
if playerHealth <= 0:
  print("Game over, You Died")
    

#Defeated First Enemy
while True:
  print("'You defeated the Semi-Smart Training Dummy, Congrats'\n...")
  time.sleep(5)
  replit.clear()
  print("'That's mearly the beginning though, that was actually the tutorial, so if you struggled it's not looking good for you'\n...")
  print("'Lucky for you though, you have a skill point to use, not that you deserve it (you killed a training dummy)'\nPress [enter] to continue")
  input()
  break
replit.clear()



#First Skill Choice
while True:
  healthSkill = 0
  damageSkill = 0
  defenseSkill = 0
  print("1. Health: " + str(healthSkill) + " (This affects total health)")
  print("2. Damage: " + str(damageSkill) + " (This affects damage done)")
  print("3. Defense: " + str(defenseSkill) + " (This affects damage taken)")
  skillChoice1 = input("What would you like to put your point into:\n")
  if skillChoice1 == "1":
    healthSkill = healthSkill + 1
    playerHealth = playerHealth + 25
  if skillChoice1 == "2":
    damageSkill = damageSkill + 1
  if skillChoice1 == "3":
    defenseSkill = defenseSkill + 1
  replit.clear()
  print("Your stats are now:\n...")
  print("1. Health: " + str(healthSkill) + " (This affects total health)")
  print("2. Damage: " + str(damageSkill) + " (This affects damage done)")
  print("3. Defense: " + str(defenseSkill) + " (This affects damage taken)")
  print("Press [enter] to continue")
  break


#Next Enemy
while True:
  input()
  replit.clear()
  print("'Now that you made it past the beginning, I'll leave you to it'\n...")
  print("'You will proceed to fight 10 bosses, progressivly getting harder, beat them all and you win'")
  print("'Lose, well it's 'game over', meaning you restart completely'\n...")
  print("'Well goodluck and enjoy, press [enter] to start'")
  input()
  replit.clear()
  break



#Second Enemy (Rock'em Stock'em)
enemyRockemStockemHealth = 100
enemyRockemStockemMiss = 7
enemyRockemStockemDamageHit = 5
playerHealth = 50
if healthSkill == 1:
  playerHealth = 75
if classChoice == "Sentinal":
  enemyRockemStockemDamageMiss = 6
  enemyRockemStockemDamageHit = 4
while playerHealth > 0:
  while enemyRockemStockemHealth > 0:
    print("Level 2 Rockem Stockem")
    print("HP:" + str(enemyRockemStockemHealth) + "/100\n...") 
    print(name)
    if healthSkill == 1:
      print("HP:" + str(playerHealth) + "/75\n...")
    elif healthSkill == 0 :
      print("HP:" + str(playerHealth) + "/50\n...")
    print ("The Rock'em Stock'em strikes when you never expect, you know that, and it makes you shiver\n...")
    print("'1. Attack'\n...")
    print("'2. Defend'")
    myChoiceRockem1 = input("What would you like to do? (type the number):\n")
  
    #Attack
    if myChoiceRockem1 == "1":
      replit.clear()
      print("Please choose an attack:\n1. Power Attack (50% chance to hit, deals increased damage)\n...\n2. Light Attack (Guarenteed hit, minimal damage)\n...\n3. Critical Attack (20% chance to hit, massive damage)\n...\n")
      attackChoice = input()
    
    
      if attackChoice == "2":
          universalChance1 = random.randint(0,100)
          #if class is warrior and is sucessful
          if universalChance1 > 10:
            if classChoice == "Warrior":
              lightAttackChance1 = 3
              replit.clear()
              print("You delt " + str(lightAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
              enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - lightAttackChance1
              print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
              playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
              time.sleep(2.5)
              replit.clear()
            
            #if class is not warrior
            if classChoice != "Warrior":
              lightAttackChance2 = 2
              replit.clear()
              print("You delt " + str(lightAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
              enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - lightAttackChance2
              print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
              playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
              time.sleep(2.5)
              replit.clear()
          #If light attack is unnsucessful
          if universalChance1 <= 10: 
            replit.clear()
            print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
            print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyRockemStockemMiss) + " damage\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemMiss
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
         
        
            
      #Power attack choice
      if attackChoice == "1":
        #if class is warrior
        universalChance2 = random.randint(0,100)
        #if class is warrior and is sucessful
        if universalChance2 > 50:
          if classChoice == "Warrior":
            powerAttackChance1 = random.randint(6,8)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(powerAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
            enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - powerAttackChance1
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear() 
          #if class is not warrior
          if classChoice != "Warrior":
            powerAttackChance2 = random.randint(5,7)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(powerAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
            enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - powerAttackChance2
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
        #If power attack is unnsucessful
        if universalChance2 <= 50: 
          replit.clear()
          print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
          print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyRockemStockemMiss) + " damage\n...")
          playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemMiss
          time.sleep(2.5)
          replit.clear()
      
          
      #Critical attack choice
      if attackChoice == "3":
          #if class is warrior
        universalChance3 = random.randint(0,100)
        #if class is warrior and is sucessful
        if universalChance3 > 80:
          if classChoice == "Warrior":
            criticalAttackChance1 = random.randint(10,15)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(criticalAttackChance1) + " damage\n...")
            enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - criticalAttackChance1
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
          
          #if class is not warrior
          if classChoice != "Warrior":
            criticalAttackChance2 = random.randint(5,7)
            replit.clear()
            print("You delt " + str(criticalAttackChance2) + " damage to enemy\n...")
            enemyRockemStockemHealth = enemyRockemStockemHealth - criticalAttackChance2
            print("The dummy delt " + str(enemyRockemStockemDamageHit) + " damage to you\n...")
            playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemDamageHit
            time.sleep(2.5)
            replit.clear()
          
        #If critical attack is unnsucessful
        if universalChance3 <= 80: 
          replit.clear()
          print("You missed your attack, what a shame\n...")
          print("The dummy now laughs at your failure and deals " + str(enemyRockemStockemMiss) + " damage\n...")
          playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyRockemStockemMiss
          time.sleep(2.5)
          replit.clear()
        

print("Game Over, You Died")
gameRestart = input("Press [enter] to restart game: ")
```

This is the revised character creation:

```
import time
import replit
import random


# Character Creation and Intro
def choose_name() -> str:
  print("....")
  name = input("Please choose a character name: ")
  print(f"Hello {name} please press [enter] to proceed\n....")
  input()
  replit.clear()
  return name
 
def choose_class() -> str:
  print("You will now choose a class\n...")
  print("The classes available are:\n....")
  all_classes = {
    "Warrior": "This class has increased damage, and base defense and luck stats",
    "Sentinal": "This class has increased defense, and base defense and luck stats",
    "Joker": "This class has increased luck, and base damage and defense stats",
  }
  for c in all_classes:
    print(c)
  print("....")
  already_described = set()
  while True:
    if len(already_described) == len(all_classes):
      print("You have already learned about all the classes, please make a selection")
      break
    choice = input("If you would like a description of the class, type their name [type 'r' to go straight to class selection]: ")
    if choice == "r":
      break
    elif choice not in all_classes:
      print("That is not one of the classes")
    elif choice in already_described:
      print("You already learned about that class")
    else:
      print (all_classes[choice])
      already_described.add(choice)
  while True: 
    replit.clear()
    classChoice = input("Please select a class: ")
    if classChoice not in all_classes:
      print("That is not one of the classes")
    else:
      return classChoice
name, charClass = choose_name(), choose_class()
char_name = name + " the " + charClass
```

Any input is appreciated, and learning code has been probably one of the interesting things i've ever done. I am currently 17 and am looking to work in software as a career.

Comment: Your code is super heavy with code repetition and duplication, the elif ladder is too high, and same strings reappear numerous times, you should split your code into functions and put your strings into Enums.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to programming! Keep it up and don't be disheartened if you encounter stumbling blocks. It's a long road to proficiency but you've already taken the first few steps.

You have no functions - and you sorely need them. It will not immediately be natural to feel for the seams in code and determine reasonable places to separate code into functions, so to begin, just "guess". A reasonable guideline which will get you headed in the right direction is: don't leave any code in the global namespace; don't write any functions longer than your handspan on the screen (say ~50 lines). Don't pass around state in the global namespace; instead pass state around in parameters and return values.

`Sentinal` is spelled `Sentinel`, `unnsucessful` `unsuccessful`, `delt` `dealt`, `mearly` `merely`, and `sucessful` `successful`.

Consider using interpolated f-strings, as in

```
f"So a brave {classChoice} you are"
```

In Python, PEP8 recommends that names like `classChoice` are instead `class_choice`.

I encourage you to work on these, and once you've moved everything to subroutines post a new question with your revised code.

Answer (score 2):

Great Job. This is quite a nice start. People here have commented that the code lacks functions and I do agree. So, in the review, I am just going to focus on that aspect. It would be quite counter-productive for you as a beginner to get a kitchen sink review and get confused about what the most important improvements are.

If you closely look at your code most of the time spent is in input processing. Selecting a player's class; choosing whether to attack or defend; choosing a skill; choosing an attack choice all follow a similar pattern. As shown below:

```
print some message -> get player input -> validate input -> perform action
```

The only difference in all these cases is the `message` that is initially printed. The `choices` a player can make and the `action` to perform. So keeping that in mind we can create a function that looks like this

```
def input_choice(message : str, choices : List[str], start : int = 0) -> int:
    
    print(message)
    input_msg = '\r\n'.join((f'{i}. {choice}' for i, choice, in enumerate(choices, start)))
    input_msg += f'\r\nPlease select a number from [{start}-{start+len(choices)-1}]: '
    error_string = f'Invalid input please select a number from [{start}-{start+len(choices)-1}]'
    while choice_str := input(input_msg):
        try:
            choice = int(choice_str)
            if(start > choice >= start + len(choices)):
                print(error_string)
                continue
            
            print(f'You Selected: {choices[choice - start]}')
            return choice
        except:
            print(error_string)
```

Here is an example of how to use it for selecting player class.

```
class Class(Enum):
    WARRIOR = auto()
    SENTINAL = auto()
    JOKER = auto()

def get_enum_names(enum):
    return [e.name.capitalize() for e in Class]

player_class = Class(
    input_choice(
        'Your options are:',
        get_enum_names(Class),
        start=1
    )
)
```

Notice what I did here. I am using `Enum` from the standard library to create player `Class`. This will enable me to have a single place where different player `Class`es are enumerated, pun intended. The `input_choice` is generic and takes a list of choices and a message, gets the user `input`, and validates it. The terminal output looks something like this.

```
Your options are:
1. Warrior
2. Sentinal
3. Joker
Please select a number from [1-3]: 1
You Selected: Warrior
```

It also handles cases where a wrong input is provided making the code robust.
Think about where else you can distill the essence of your code into generic functions like this and your code will be easier to develop and maintain. It is always a pleasure to see someone new take on larger programming challenges so looking forward to another iteration of your code.